# Find a functional F such that F(g)=<g,h> doesn't hold

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $H=C[0,1]$ with inner product $<f,g>=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx$. Find a functional $F\in H^*$ such that there isn't $h\in H$ satisfying $F(g)=<g,h>$, then justify.

My question is is there a way to approach this problem to solve it?  I find these "find the functionals" problems come out of the blue the solution.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in [0,1]$ and consider the linear functional $L_x \in H^*$ where $L_x(f) = f(x)$, just point evaluation at $x$.  Now, observe that if there was a continuous function $g \in H$ from which we could express $L_x$ uniquely we would have

$$
L_x(h) \;\; =\;\; \int_0^1 h(y) g(y)dy \;\; =\;\; h(x)
$$

but the only way this could work is if we integrated $h$ with respect to Dirac measure: $h(x) = \int_0^1 h(y) \delta_x(y)$.  But the Dirac measure is not a function (and if it were, it would be far from continuous) and hence not an element of $H$.

Comment: The way the question was worded, it seems that the space $H$ uses the $L^2$ norm. Evaluation at a point is not bounded in this case.

Comment: I don't know what an $L^2$ norm or what the Dirac measure is.  H is the space of continuous functions from [0,1] though

Comment: @Tom The thing is that talking about boundedness of linear functionals is not really "well-defined" in this case since $H$ is neither a Hilbert nor a Banach space with respect to $L^2$ norm.  The continuous functions on $L^2$ are complete with respect to the $sup$ norm.  Either way, clarification would be good in knowing whether $H^*$ was the set of bounded linear functionals, or all linear functionals.

Comment: The definition I have of dual space is $V^*=L(V, F)$ where F is a field of any sort.  We have worked with linear functionals throughout the course and have never mentioned any specifics, so have never mentioned bounded linear functionals.  Also, the practice question doesn't give more details than I have stated.  So I am quite certain it's all linear functionals.  Thanks @Tom and Mnifldz!

Comment: @user218512 Is this for a linear algebra class, or for analysis?  I'm assuming your notation is that $L(V,\mathbb{F})$ is the set of linear maps from a vector space $V$ into the field $\mathbb{F}$?  It's helpful to define/explain these notations in your problem statement since not all notations are used uniformly by all math practitioners.

Comment: Linear Algebra.  Sorry, I'll keep this in mind for the future.  And yes you are correct it's the set of linear maps